# Deploying ASP.NET 2.0 Application in Sharepoint site

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint

I Had created a ASp.net website ...
I had a share point site also..

My target is that i want to deploy my ASP.net website with my share point Site....

And 2ndly i had created a web form in my asp.net web site
it consist of 3 text box and button ....
the value from the form should be stored Sharepoint Coustom list

3rdly I want ot access Share point list item from my sharepoint site into my ASp.net website...

Can any one help me in these issue? or tell the write direction....

Comment: Please correct your spelling mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

From your description the simplest solution would not to have a seperate asp.net web site. But create a SharePoint Form against a SharePoint List

Answer (score 0):

How about [SharePoint Application pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb418732%28office.12%29.aspx) instead of ASP.net web app?.